# Python Process Pool signal handling

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals, pool, sigterm

I have a `multiprocessing.Pool` running tasks that I wan't to exit gracefully in case of a terminate by handling the `SIGTERM` signal

This is my code example (used python 3.9)

```py
import os
import signal
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


class SigTermException(Exception):
    pass


def sigtermhandler(signum, frame):
    raise SigTermException('sigterm')


def f():
    print(os.getpid())
    try:
        while True:
            print("loop")
            time.sleep(5)
    except SigTermException:
        print("Received SIGTERM")


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigtermhandler)
    pool = Pool()

    pool.apply_async(f)
    print("wait 5")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Terminating")
    pool.terminate()
    print("Joining")
    pool.join()
    print("Exiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I was expecting to print

```
...
Terminating
Received SIGTERM
Joining
Exiting
```

However it seems it doesn't go past `pool.terminate()`

Here's an example

```
wait 5
92363
loop
Terminating
loop
Received SIGTERM
```

Performing a `ps` I see the following

```
  92362 pts/0    S+     0:00  |   |   \_ python signal_pool.py
  92363 pts/0    S+     0:00  |   |       \_ python signal_pool.py
```

So it looks like the child process is still 'alive'

Also tested the solution mentioned [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue38227) to no avail

Any hints o help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your worker function, `f`, runs forever yet your main process sleeps just for 5 seconds and then calls `terminate` on the pool which would result in killing any running tasks. This contradicts your saying you would like to have your tasks exit gracefully in case of receiving a SIGTERM because as it now stands, they will not exit gracefully in the absence of a SIGTERM.

So I would think the main process should be waiting as long as necessary for the submitted task or tasks to complete -- this is the usual situation, right? It also seems that when I tried this and issued a *kill -15* command, perhaps because the main process is just in a wait state waiting for the submitted task to complete, that the worker function alone handled this and the signal was never passed to the main process. I therefore did not need a `try/except` block in the main proceess.

```py
import os
import signal
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


class SigTermException(Exception):
    pass


def sigtermhandler(signum, frame):
    raise SigTermException('sigterm')


def f():
    print(os.getpid())
    try:
        while True:
            print("loop")
            time.sleep(5)
    except SigTermException:
        print("Received SIGTERM")


def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigtermhandler)
    pool = Pool()
    async_result = pool.apply_async(f)
    print("waiting for task to complete ...")
    async_result.get() # wait for task to complete
    pool.close()
    print("Joining")
    pool.join()
    print("Exiting")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Printed:

```None
waiting for task to complete ...
98
loop
Received SIGTERM
Joining
Exiting
```

You can also just do:

```py
def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigtermhandler)
    pool = Pool()
    pool.apply_async(f)
    print("waiting for all tasks to complete ...")
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print("Exiting")
```

Comment: the provided code is actually just an example of what I intended to do. It mimics the scenario where the signal is received by the main process. The main process handles the signal and issues a terminate and waits for the child process to finish.

However as shown the pool gets stuck at `terminate`